# "ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN." cassandra

Tags: database-design, cassandra

I have created my table like this..

```
CREATE TABLE test1.mytest (
    id text,
    year text,
    time bigint,
    crtby text,
    data text,
    postid text,
    upby text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, year), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)
```

I want to sort my data based on time key.

```
SELECT * FROM test1.mytest WHERE id ='b' ORDER BY time asc ALLOW FILTERING ;
```

when i try the above command i am getting

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly describes the reason for the failure. Your primary key is *id* and *year* and then further clustering is done on *time* key.

Cassandra needs to know the *id* and the *year* and only then it can do an order by on *time*.

Since you are not always using the partitioning key (id, year) in queries, to do order by time, you will have to use Materialized Views. More details can be found [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views).